# Excel spill pivot range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For a normal excel table I can refer to the tablename as range `=Table1` if I want to spill the whole table.

Is there a way to spill a range using the pivottable name as range, or do I have to use a normal range like `=A1:B3`

Comment: To me it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. `=Table1` already is the reference, what else do you expect and why? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: When referencing a regular table range I can reference the table name - not so with a Pivot table.  So if I want to retrieve all data in a regular table I just refer to the table name and all values spill - with a pivot I have to use a reference like ```=A1:B3```

Comment: If you are able to use the Pivotby function, you can access it as spill range e.g. if I have =PIVOTBY(A2:A7,B2:B7,C2:C7,SUM) in E2,I can use= E2# etc.